# Using an if/else statment to check that enum arguments exist

Tags: c, enums, arguments

I'm having a slight issue with my current piece of code and trying to check that arguments have been passed to enum before trying to continue with the program;

```
 enum arg {argName, sineArg, sampleArg, argC}eargs;

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    long samplingRate = atol(argv[sampleArg]);
    float sineFreq = atof(argv[sineArg]);
    if (argC < eargs ){
        printf("Usage: sineFreq\tsamplingRate\n");
    }else{}
  }
```

The code compiles fine, although when run without arguments the program returns "Segmentation fault: 11" instead of the usage message that I want to print to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage check is against `eargs` that has nothing to with the number of command line arguments passed. No matter how many arguments you pass, `eargs` is always going to be `0`.

Also you should do the check *before* using any of the command line arguments. Place the condition at the start of `main()`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum arg {argName, sineArg, sampleArg, argC}eargs;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  /* if ( argc < 3) would be explicit and clear here */
  if (argc < argC ) { /* You expect at least two arguments */
    printf("Usage: sineFreq\tsamplingRate\n");
    return 1; // return from main on failure
  }

  long samplingRate = atol(argv[sampleArg]);
  float sineFreq = atof(argv[sineArg]);

  ....
}
```

I have also included standard headers as you are using `printf()` and `atol()`

Comment: I think I misunderstood the use of the final enum argument, you basically just check how many arguments there are against the index of the last argument in enum?

Comment: Yes. If you don't assign any values to enum then they start with `0`. It works as if you define it with: `enum{argName=0, sineArg=1, sampleArg=2, argC=3}eargs;` But if you later insert more elements enum, then `argc` will be different. E.g. If you do: `enum arg {argName, sineArg, newArg, sampleArg, argC}eargs;` then `argC` will be 4 now.

Answer (score 1):

you have to do the check before accessing `argv[...]`

EDIT: the check itself is wrong too (`eargs` is undefined; you should write

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < argC)         /* --> you should change you naming conventions! */
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    long samplingRate = atol(argv[sampleArg]);
```

Comment: I've changed the code around quickly and the compiling worked, but it still just returns the same message to console.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change `argC`  to `argc`, in the if statement...c is case-sensitive!!!

Comment: Are you talking about the 'argc' declaration in 'main'? I've just changed it all to the same ('argC') and it still returns the same message to console

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code without arguments, this

```
 long samplingRate = atol(argv[sampleArg]);
```

accesses argv[2], which is **undefined behavior**, since you don't provide enough args (there are only argv[0] = program name and argv[1] = NULL indicating the end of the argv[]).